# Confused about the consistency guarantee of zookeeper (Sequential vs Eventual Consistency)

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, distributed-system, consistency

As I understand, Zookeeper enforces "sequential consistency" which states any execution is the same as if all read/write ops were executed in some global ordering. Basically, a client may see stale data but it's guaranteed to see values in the order of the writes which are linearized.

I have two confusions

**1. How is the ordering guarantee from sequential consistency preserved when a node goes down? For example, what happens in a following scenario?**

1. Write x=1
2. Write x=2
3. Node A has the most recent value x=2, Node B is still on old value x=1
4. A client reads x=2 from Node A
5. Node A goes down.
6. A client is now connected to Node B.
7. A client now reads x=1 from Node B.

Doesn't this break the ordering guarantee provided by the sequential consistency?

**2. Am I correct in saying that all eventual consistency model provides an ordering guarantee as long as a client is always reading from the same node?**

Is the lack of ordering guarantee in eventual consistency due to the fact that a client can read from any node and is not tied to a specific node when reading a value?

(Wouldn't systems that implement sequential consistency suffer from the same issue though in a scenario where a node goes down and a client is forced to read from a client with a stale data? Kinda goes back to my question #1)

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The following definition of SC I find more useful. An execution is SC if it has the same outcome as a different execution that has the following properties: total order over all loads/stores. This order is consistent with the program order of each process (thread/cpu). A load sees the most recent store before it in the memory order.

Comment: So it isn't only the writes that get 'linearized' also the reads are linearized in this total order.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zookeeper. But in other systems like Raft, you need consensus on the reads and writes. So when there is a network partition and Node A and B get separated, then the system becomes unavailable, because it is impossible to reach a consensus. If we would have Node A/B/C and node C gets separated due to a network partition, then read/writes on node A/B can still succeed because they can still reach consensus.

Comment: So a client can only successfully communicate with the nodes that can reach consensus. And as a consequence, you keep a total order on the operations. Raft provides linearizability, which is even more strict than sequential consistency.

Comment: As soon as clients are allowed to communicate with nodes that can't form consensus, you can potentially run into inconsistent behavior (so lack of order). So it might be you see X=1, X=2 then back to X=1. But the advantage is that you are available (CAP theorem).

Comment: There is a plethora of consistency models for example causality. For causality, as long as you keep communicating to the same nodes, your system will preserve causality; so causality is sticky available. Sequential consistency requires quorum and if quorum can't be reached, the system becomes unavailable. For more info see  https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/sequential and https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/causal.

Comment: It isn't sufficient for a client to keep talking to the same node because other clients could communicate with other nodes and access the same variables and you could end up with a situation that can't be explained by e.g. sequential consistency.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is sequential consistency. That's it, no restrictions on the nodes going down/up or connecting to the same node. The question is, how we make sure the client handles the situation without reaching a wrong conclusion. Here is how:

1. Each event has a version number (e,1) (e'',2) (e''',3)
2. The client notes down the version number (high water mark) after processing each node.
3. If the system (Zookeeper) ever goes back in time, delivering an event older than client's high water mark. Client waits, ignoring these event.

Only with sequential consistency, the client can ignore redeliveries and avoid processing duplicate events. So the client avoids going back and forth in time.